# Find data by two values in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Structure is

```
{
    id        :  12345,
    userIDs   :  [ "1", "2", "3"]
}
```

How to write query in nodejs to find userId is present in document or not on the based on id? So we have to pass two values in query first is ID and second is userId, am I correct?

Comment: I find the solution :

`Structure.findOne( {'id' : id, "userIDs" : userId },
         '-_id' , function (err, u) { 
       if(!err) {
                      //callback            
                } else {
                    // callback
                }
}`

Comment: I'm glad you managed to solve your question. Please post your own answer as well and mark it as the answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Structure.findOne( {'id' : id, "userIDs" : userId },
         '-_id' , function (err, u) { 
       if(!err) {
                      //callback

                } else {
                    // callback
                }
}`

u return null if not match otherwise it return whole document.